# how to git checkout all files besides one folder from a different branch and keep committing the folder in the same branch?

Tags: git

I have two branches (**branch A** and **B**) besides the master branch. For simplicity let's say both of them has a directory called `mydir`, and `mydir` has a lot of folders and files. After I finished changing multiple files in the `mydir` folder and push it to **branch B**, I want to remain in **branch B** but checkout everything in **branch A** besides the files in `mydir` folder to test the files I just changed. I only know how to do checkout single file from other branch, but how can I do what I want without repeating checkout for each files in **branch A**?
(I would like to continue editing/committing the files in `mydir` of **branch B** after this)

Answer (score 1):

Use `git checkout` or `git restore` with [exclude path](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-exclude):

```bash
git checkout branch-A . ":(exclude)mydir"
git restore --source=branch-A . ":!mydir"
```

These two commands are equivalent. And these two examples of using exclude path are equivalent.